# Processing va_list piece by piece

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

The following program works on a 64-bit Linux machine, but crashes on a 32-bit Linux machine.

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>

void proc_int(std::va_list va)
{
    std::cout << va_arg(va, int);
}

void proc_str(std::va_list va)
{
    std::cout << va_arg(va, const char*);
}

void outputv(std::va_list va)
{
    proc_int(va);
    std::cout << " ";
    proc_str(va);
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void output(int dummy, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, dummy);
    outputv(va);
    va_end(va);
}

int main()
{
    output(0, 42, "hello");
}
```

I believe this is because `va_list` is `char*` on 32-bit but `struct __va_list_tag[1]` on 64-bit.  What changes can I make to make this program portable, preferably without changing the signature of `outputv`?

Comment: Pass by pointer: http://ideone.com/bhKalu

Comment: @n.m. On 64-bit, error: cannot convert `__va_list_tag**` to `__va_list_tag (*)[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work whether va_list is typedefed to be an array or not:

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using my_va_list = std::decay<std::va_list>::type;

void proc_int(my_va_list &va)
{
    std::cout << va_arg(va, int);
}

void proc_str(my_va_list &va)
{
    std::cout << va_arg(va, const char*);
}

void outputv(std::va_list va)
{
    my_va_list mva = va;
    proc_int(mva);
    std::cout << " ";
    proc_str(mva);
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Not guaranteed to work with all implementations, but at least under gcc, clang and vc++ it works in both 32 and 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 3):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_list),

> If a `va_list` instance is created, passed to another function, and used via `va_arg` in that function, then any subsequent use in the calling function should be preceded by a call to `va_end`

It's not wholly clear whether that (*subsequent use*) includes passing to another function, but it's certainly plausible.

Checking local (Linux) man page for comparison:

> If `ap` *[the va_list]* is passed to a function that uses `va_arg(ap,type)` then the value of ap is undefined after the return of that function

So you're simply not allowed to pass the `va_list` around and use it the way you are, and the 32-bit version just happens to get away with it.

> What changes can I make to make this program portable, preferably without changing the signature of outputv?

Well, just don't pass the `va_list` into other functions and expect it to still work afterwards:

```
void outputv(std::va_list va)
{
    std::cout << va_arg(va, int);
    std::cout << " ";
    std::cout << va_arg(va, const char *);
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ugh. I have some legacy code that passes a lot of `va_list&` around.  But `va_list&` can't bind to a `va_list` parameter if the latter is an array that was transformed to a pointer.

Comment: Most likely the breakage is due to the change in calling convention from 32-bit, but that doesn't help you fix it. You might want to ask a question about how to implement whatever you're actually doing, without using `va_list`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C standard (whose varargs functionality is directly included into C++), C99, section 7.15 paragraph 3 (emphasis mine):

> The type declared is `va_list` which is an object type suitable for
>   holding information needed by the macros `va_start`, `va_arg`,
>   `va_end`, and `va_copy`. If access to the varying arguments is
>   desired, the called function shall declare an object (generally
>   referred to as `ap` in this subclause) having type `va_list`. **The
>   object `ap` may be passed as an argument to another function; if that
>   function invokes the `va_arg` macro with parameter `ap`, the value of
>   `ap` in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to
>   the `va_end` macro prior to any further reference to `ap`.** *212)*

Since you are passing the `va_list` to the function and it is using `va_arg` inside it, you cannot re-use that `va_list` after that function returns. And the "212)" note gives a solution:

> 212) It is permitted to create a pointer to a `va_list` and pass that
>   pointer to another function, in which case the original function may
>   make further use of the original list after the other function
>   returns.